# Selectively emitting values by an accumulated value from an Observable

Tags: scala, rx-java, observable

I have an Observable of `Foo`'s which contain a `timestamp` field. I want to group these objects into "chunks", and then select the object with the most recent timestamp.

A "chunk" is a group of `Foo`'s that occur within a `cutoff`, in this example it would be 1-7 since these occur within 300 units of each other, and 8-10 likewise.

Here is a toy example:

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable

case class Foo(id: Int, timestamp: Long)

val timestamp: Long = 1447118577892L
val cutOff: Long = 300L
val elements = List(
  Foo(1, timestamp),
  Foo(2, timestamp + 50),
  Foo(3, timestamp + 100),
  Foo(4, timestamp + 150),
  Foo(5, timestamp + 200),
  Foo(6, timestamp + 250),
  Foo(7, timestamp + 300),    // chunk 1
  Foo(8, timestamp + 500),
  Foo(9, timestamp + 550),
  Foo(10, timestamp + 600),   // chunk 2
  Foo(11, timestamp + 800))

val obs: Observable[Foo] = Observable.from(elements)
```

So I would expect a Foo's 7 and 10 to be produced from this observable. Naturally, I don't want to block when doing this.

Comment: How do you define a "chunk"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood correctly, this is exactly what the [debounce](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#debounce%28rx.functions.Func1%29) operator does:

> Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable, except that
>   it drops items emitted by the source Observable that are followed by
>   another item within a computed debounce duration.

You can have it return the last Timestamp from the source observable after no timestamps were observed for a period of time (i.e. the most recent timestamp in each "chunk")